# QT 5.7 Serial Port reads very slow

Tags: c++, performance, qt5, qtserialport

I am very new to programming and I am teaching myself. I wrote a application to poll a number of requests from a control unit . I basically continuously send various read commands to the Control unit and read back the response .My program works and i successfully send commands and receive answers . But the reading is very slow ( i have a 100 ms timeout in my code to ensure i get the complete reply ) 
I have a program for the same control unit that was written by a professional coder in C++ , in his program he polls every 30 ms and i always receive the complete answer in that time frame . I have the same settings 57K baud 8 bits 1 stop bit and no parity . However my QT code takes almost 100 ms to receive the answer.
In my code i read the first 2 bytes ( first byte is the message identifier and second byte is the remainder of the message length) then i read in a loop until the total message length is equal to the message length byte +1 (the +1 is there to include the first byte ) . I am a wits end as to why my code is so slow in QT when i know its know the Hardware that's the limiting factor . The requests are always 3 bytes and the reply varies from 3 to 61 bytes . Please help me to point me to my error. If i remove the timeout i always have short reads . So far i also tried read(all) but with the same result .
Below is the extract from my code where i read the response . The full code is at https://github.com/MarkusIppy/PowerTune

```
//Error handling 
QTime startTime = QTime::currentTime(); 
int timeOut = 100; // timeout in milisec. 
QByteArray recvData = m_serialport->read(2);  // reading first two bytes of received message to determine lenght of ecpected message 
int msgLen = recvData[1]; //Total message Lenght excluding the first byte 
while ( recvData.size() <= (msgLen+1) ) 
{ 
    if ( startTime.msecsTo(QTime::currentTime()) > timeOut ) break; 
    recvData += m_serialport->read(msgLen+1-recvData.size()); 
} 

if (msgLen +1 == recvData.length())  //if the received data lenght equals the message lenght from lenght byte + identifier byte (correct message lenght received ) 
{ 
    qDebug() << "Received data OK"<<msgLen +1; 
    if(requestIndex <= 61){requestIndex++;} 
    else{requestIndex = 58;} 
    readData(recvData); 
} 
else   //if the lenght of the received message does not correspond with the expected lenght repeat the request 
{ 
    qDebug() << "Received data lenght NIO"; 
    readData(recvData); 
    qDebug() << "Request Message again"<< requestIndex; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry, I don't have enough time to go through your project and from the code you've provided I cannot be 100% sure what the cause is. My best guess though is that the problem in this case is that you wait explicitly for the data to be received and the events processing is somehow delayed or does not take place at all.

Anyway, here you have a couple of suggestions:

1. Use *QTimer* for timeouts instead of *QTime*.
2. Learn about the [Qt5's signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and use them to read from the serial port asynchronously.

I use the *QSerialPort* by connecting its `bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)` and `readyRead()` signals to slots of my program, let's say `on_bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)` and `on_readyRead()`. Then I send request to the target device and in the `on_readyRead()` slot I process the result. With each send command I start a *QTimer* with its `timeout()` signal connected to a `on_timeout()` slot of my application. This way I could monitor whether the device responds in time or not, as well as to have the data as soon as it comes. You may also use the `errorOccurred(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)` signal of the *QSerialPort* to check if there is a problem with the transmission.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi @scopchanov , i couldn't edit my comment anymore .

Comment: Hi @scopchanov , i couldn't edit my comment anymore . I have started editing my code i already used signals and slots and trying to implement your recommendations . I looked at the asynchron reader example of QT and see this is exactly the way you describe it . I found another issue in my code as well , i did not know that one message might get sent in multiple chunks and trigger the readyread slot more then once . I made provision for that now and append the message until it has the expected length including a 5000 ms timeout. I am only able to test on the actual hardware end of next week

Comment: @Markus Ippy, yes, the message does not come in one piece and you have to construct it by yourself. This is how I do it in my programms as well. `void MySerial::on_readyRead() { if (!m_port->isOpen()) { return; } dataReady(m_port->readAll()); }` And from here: `void MySerial::dataReady(const QByteArray &pdu) { m_buffer.append(pdu); if (pdu.contains('\n')) { processResponse(m_buffer); } }`

Answer (score 2):

Changed my code slightly again and now it works perfectly on the actual Hardware 
Below is my ready to read Slot :

```
void Serial::readyToRead()
{
    qDebug() << "ready read";
    if(ecu == 0)
    {
        m_readData.append(m_serialport->readAll());
        Bytesexpected = m_readData[1]+1;
        qDebug() << "readdata current" <<m_readData.toHex();
        if (Bytesexpected == m_readData.size())
        {
            m_timer.stop();
            if(requestIndex <= 62){requestIndex++;}
            else{requestIndex = 59;}
            readData(m_readData);
            Serial::clear();
            m_readData.clear();
            Serial::sendRequest(requestIndex);
        }
        if (Bytesexpected != m_readData.size())
        {
            qDebug() << "starting timer";
            m_timer.start(5000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have so far ( just posting the important parts of my cpp file ) 
This code works now almost perfectly with my message emulator. It polls now as expected but the timeout gets always triggered after 5 seconds ( i need to change it to only trigger if there is no message comming ) . I will only  be able to test it on the actual hardware end of next week . 
This is what i have so far :

```
    void Serial::initSerialPort()
    {
    if (m_serialport)
        delete m_serialport;
    m_serialport = new SerialPort(this);
    connect(this->m_serialport,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readyToRead()));
    connect(m_serialport, static_cast<void (QSerialPort::*)    (QSerialPort::SerialPortError)>(&QSerialPort::error),
            this, &Serial::handleError);
    connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Serial::handleTimeout);
     m_timer.start(5000);


    }

    void Serial::readyToRead() 
    {
    if(ecu == 0)
    {

        m_readData.append(m_serialport->readAll());
        Bytesexpected = m_readData[1]+1;
        if (Bytesexpected == m_readData.size())
        {
            if(requestIndex <= 62){requestIndex++;}
            else{requestIndex = 59;}
            readData(m_readData); // message for processing
            Serial::clear();
            m_readData.clear();
        }
    //Timeout
        if (!m_timer.isActive())
            m_timer.start(5000);

}
}

     void Serial::handleTimeout()
    {
    qDebug() << "Timeout";
    //request Data Again
    QString fileName = "Errors.txt";
    QFile mFile(fileName);
    if(!mFile.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text)){
        qDebug() << "Could not open file for writing";
    }
    QTextStream out(&mFile);
    out << "Timeout Request Index " << int(requestIndex)<< " lenght received  "<< int(m_readData.length())<< " Bytes "<< " Expected Bytes "<< int(Bytesexpected)<< " bytes " <<" Message "<< QByteArray(m_readData.toHex()) <<endl;
    mFile.close();
    Serial::clear();
    m_readData.clear();
    Serial::sendRequest(requestIndex);
    }

    void Serial::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError serialPortError)
    {
    if (serialPortError == QSerialPort::ReadError) {
        QString fileName = "Errors.txt";
        QFile mFile(fileName);
        if(!mFile.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text)){
            qDebug() << "Could not open file for writing";
        }
        QTextStream out(&mFile);
        out << "Serial Error " << (m_serialport->errorString()) <<endl;
        mFile.close();
        qDebug() <<"Serialport Error" <<(m_serialport->errorString());
    }
    }
```

Comment: When you restart the timer ,or when you are ok you have to disconnect the signals ,like:    ```disconnect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Serial::handleTimeout);```